# Remove @mentions, urls and # symbols using python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Trying to remove @mentions, urls and # symbols from twitter data using python.
To get

```
lets take action! fitness health
```

from

```
@BBCNews lets take action! #fitness #health https://www.url.com
```

Code:

```py
import re
df1 = re.sub(r'(?:\@|https?\://|#)\S+', '', df)
```

But this produces "lets take action! ", I'm having a hard time fixing my regex, but I think I'm close. How can I fix my regex?

Comment: The variable "df" leads me to believe you're using pandas to do this... am I mistaken?

Comment: But the pattern you have will also remove `#` from anywhere in the string. What if there is `4#4` or `# 44`? Should it result in `44`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern is incorrect because you're specifying the removal of `\S+` chars after the `#` chars as well. Instead, change your pattern to,

```
>>> re.sub(r'(@|https?)\S+|#', '', text)
' lets take action! fitness health '
```

**Regex Breakdown**

```
(@       # match '@'
 |       # OR
 https?  # "http" or "https", followed by...
)
\S+      # one or more characters that aren't whitespace
|        # OR
#        # hashtag
```

---

As a bonus, the 3<sup>rd</sup> party [tweet-processor](https://pypi.org/project/tweet-preprocessor/) module provides most of this functionality out-of-box, with optional customisations.

```
import preprocessor as p

p.clean(text)
# 'lets take action!'

# customise what you want removed
p.set_options(p.OPT.MENTION, p.OPT.URL,)
p.clean(text)
# 'lets take action! #fitness #health'

p.clean(text).replace('#', '')
# 'lets take action! fitness health'
```

Comment: Thank you, used the corrected version, but got an error...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    190     a callable, it's passed the Match object and must return
    191     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 192     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    193 
    194 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: @Ioio clearly that means `text` is not a string (like it should be). It's not an error with my code, I'll tell you that much.

Comment: @Ioio What is `type(df)` or `type(text)`, whatever your variable is named?

Comment: yes, thank you, that was the problem. converted the data into string. thanks a lot!

Comment: worked like a charm. Thanks! Googled for 1h before I found this solution. Mainly ```'#(\S+)'  ``` is mentioned in other solutions which removed some but not all hashtags in the tweets I am working with